# Finding the moment of inertia of a lever

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

I am required to find the moment of inertia of the lever for a project in physics. This is my attempt:

Please note that we have not been taught this yet in class so i have not been taught this officially yet.

The seperate radiuses are the distance from the fulcrum to the end of each side of the lever.

$L = 1.57m$

$r_1 = .97m$

$r_2 = .6m$

$M_{total} = 2.3 kg$

$$
I = \frac{M_{total}}{L}\int_{0}^{.97} x^2 dx + \frac{M_{total}}{L} \int_{0}^{.6} x^2 dx
$$

$$
I = \frac{M_{total}}{L}[\frac{.97^3+.6^3}{3}]
$$

$$
I = \frac{2.3(.97^3+.6^3)}{4.71} = \frac{165347}{300000}
$$

But this seems way too easy? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you did it good, and it is that easy. The expression is correct because you have:
 $I = \int x^2 dm = \int x^2 \rho dx = \rho \int x^2  dx= \frac{M_{total}}{L} \int x^2 dx $

You can always check if your calculation is correct by using a different method: by finding the moment of inertia for a standar shaped object form a [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia), and using the [parallel axis theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem):

> the parallel axis theorem  can be used to determine the mass moment of inertia of a body about any axis, given the body's moment of inertia about a parallel axis through the object's center of mass and the perpendicular distance between the axes

Comment: So its multiplied by the ratio of the mass divided by the length of the whole board? That was the big part that confused me.

Comment: @EricLawson yes, I updated the answer to show why this is correct, hope it helps

Comment: Also, if i were to use

$$
\tau_{net} = I \alpha 
$$

Since

$$
\omega_{f}^2 = \omega_i^2 + 2 \alpha \Delta \Theta
$$

$$
\tau_{net} = I \frac{\omega_f^2 - \omega_i^2}{2 \Delta \Theta}
$$

Would this be correct?

Comment: it is correct assuming $\alpha$ is a constant (because the second equation assumes that)